# What's the community consensus for cleaning up tags related to file handles?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

#### TL;DR

Can we merge, alias, or burn most of the filehandle-related tags?

#### What's the problem?

There's a really large number of poorly-differentiated tags similar to filehandle:

- [filehandle](/questions/tagged/filehandle)
- [filehandler](/questions/tagged/filehandler)
- [file-handling](/questions/tagged/file-handling)
- [file-handles](/questions/tagged/file-handles)
- [staticfilehandler](/questions/tagged/staticfilehandler)
- [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io)

Most of these don't even have descriptions. Even the ones that do aren't well-differentiated.

#### What shall we do about it?

As a community, we should decide:

1. Which of these tags actually matter.
2. Which tags can we do away with.
3. How we can optimize the proper categorization of posts related to file handles.

Anything you can do to be helpful would be...well, helpful. :)

Comment: I'd love to see someone with synonym privileges take part in this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

Turning [filehandle](/questions/tagged/filehandle), [filehandler](/questions/tagged/filehandler), [file-handling](/questions/tagged/file-handling) and [file-handles](/questions/tagged/file-handles) into synonyms for [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io) would be OK; those two are currently being used to tag questions that are all over the place. There's no common theme, nobody would ever want to watch the tag (well, they probably wouldn't for [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io) either) and there's no way to comprehend how to write a useful tag wiki for them either. Mind you, burninating the tags would probably be just as good.

[staticfilehandler](/questions/tagged/staticfilehandler) is OK though. Yes, it's an uncommon tag but it at least refers to a single particular thing from what I can see. It's not one of the bad *omnium gatherum* tags.

Comment: Currently, staticfilehandler has no tag wiki. If you think the tag adds value, would you consider writing one?

Comment: @CodeGnome While I can clearly see that it's referring to a single thing (something in C# that deals with IIS?) it's in an area that I know I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

[filehandle](/questions/tagged/filehandle) and [filehandler](/questions/tagged/filehandler) are different things, as I see them. It looks like you've identified two different concepts: file handlers and file handles. File *handlers* are mechanisms for operating with files (`read`, `write`, `unlink` etc.) while file *handles* are constructs which describe files (`FILE*`, `HANDLE`, `struct filp` etc.).

I agree that they should be flattened; perhaps merge [file-handling](/questions/tagged/file-handling) and [filehandler](/questions/tagged/filehandler) into [file-io](/questions/tagged/file-io), and have [filehandle](/questions/tagged/filehandle) be a synonym for [file-handles](/questions/tagged/file-handles).